# Bourbon Neat -- grid behavior

Tags: jekyll, bourbon, neat

I am using Bourbon Neat grid to size the widths of various divs on a web page.

**default.html**

```
<main class = "default-content">
    {{ content }}
</main>
```

**default.scss**

```
main {
    @include span-columns(6);
}
```

**page.html**

The content of this page will be pipelined to {{ content }} in default.html

```
<div class = "full-width">
</div>
```

**page.scss**

```
.full-width {
    @include span-columns(6);
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

---

**Expected and Desired Results**

The width of `<div class="full-width">` will be the full width of the parent div.

---

**Actual Results**

The width of `<div class="full-width">` is only half the width of the parent div.

---

**Conclusion**

It was my impression that the child div would be the full width of the parent div since they are both `@include span-columns(6)`. My guess is that this is not the actual result because

- These divs are not within an `@include outer-container`
- There is something in the syntax of Bourbon Neat I am missing
- Something with the pipelining of the content is messing with the grid

---

Also, if you know ... is the use of `@include outer-container` necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Neat documentation](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#span-columns)

> Specifies the number of columns an element should span. If the
>   selector is nested the number of columns of its parent element should
>   be passed as an argument as well.

If your `$grid-columns` variable is 12, in your `.full-width` expression, span is assumed to me 6 columns over 12 (half the size of the parent).

Correct expression is :

```
 .full-width {
    @include span-columns(6 of 6);
    border: 1px solid #111;
 }
```

Comment: Do you know if the use of `outer-container` is necessary or possible implications of not using this?

Comment: "Although optional, using outer-container is recommended." See http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#outer-container